# Recursively Create Hasmaps in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics, hashmap

I'm trying to create a new `HashMap` for each document I have as input. In pseudeocode I can think of something like:

```
For(eachInputDoc)
{
    Map<String, String> mapInputNumber = new HashMap<String, String>;
}
```

So that for 4 documents you would have:

```
mapInput1
mapInput2
mapInput3
mapInput4
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hm, use a HashMap.. what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want a total of 4 hashmaps, or 10, or 50 depending on whatever the input is.

Comment: You are looking for a Sequence of Maps. In Java this is often expressed as `ArrayList<HashMap<K,V>>`, where each element in the Sequence (ArrayList) represents a document (HashMap), however, it might be better later on to have: `ArrayList<Document>` and make the Maps opaque to that.

Comment: Jon is right. The declaration needs to exist at compile time and the declaration in your pseudo-code simply doesn't exist since it's inside the scope of a for (=process). Thus the solution is to seek an alternative declaration as described above and below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to declare variables dynamically. You can't do that in Java - the variables themselves are determined at compile time. However, you *could* create a list:

```
List<Map<String, String>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
for (Document doc : docs)
{
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // Populate map from doc
    maps.add(map);
}
```

Comment: I still have trouble understanding generics and code like this. In passing, keep an eye on Martijn. I think he's going places :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you make an ArrayList of HashMaps.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dynamically generate names like `mapInput1`, `mapInput2`, etc in Java. You need to think of array or `List`. Also your problem is not recursive.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
Map<MyDocClass, Map<String, String>> myDocData = new HashMapMap<MyDocClass, Map<String, String>>();
for(MyDocClass doc : myDocs) {
  Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
  // populate the data
  myDocData.put(doc, data);
}
```

Then you can easily access the data for each doc by doing

```
Map<String, String> data = myDocData.get(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know/want to reference the name of the document, you could even use a HashMap of HashMaps.

Answer (score 0):

I would have another map to hold the mapInputs something like this:

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> context = new HashMap<Integer,Map<String,String>>();
for each(inputDoc)
{
  Map<String, String> mapInput = new HashMap<String, String>();
  context.put(index,mapInput);
}
```

U have the aproach of having a List(array,linked) instead of MAP, but this depends of how you`re gonna access that inputMaps! I would say that using a ArrayList is a good one too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your hash maps into another (dynamic) container like ArrayList or other HashMap.